# Why is Firefox 57 not styling my <option> elements like other browsers?

Tags: css, firefox

The new FireFox 57 Quantum does not honor my CSS dropdown selection list styling (only the default `<select>` value is honored). In all other browsers it works as it should. How to deal with this new version FF browser in terms of using my CSS styling for all of my select's `<option>`s? Chrome displays the options correctly.

Images for how it looks in FF57 and Chrome, respectively:

[image: FF57]

[image: Chrome]

```css
input[type="date"], input[type="email"], input[type="number"], input[type="password"], input[type="text"], input[type="url"], option, select, textarea {
font-size:20px;
font-weight: 700;
font-family: "times new roman";
}
```

```html
<select id="Ultra">
     <option value="0">My first value looks good</option>
     <option value="8">text1 blalalabababalallaala</option>
     <option value="5">text2 oeleoeleleoeleloelele</option>
     <option value="77">text3 wwowowowoowoww</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `option` elements have always been notoriously difficult to style in general, let alone consistently across browsers.

Comment: This idea rarely goes over well but I would avoid styling most of the dropdown and let the device dictate how the element appears.

Comment: Still broken in Firefox 63! Apparently the developers don't care, this issue has been around for YEARS. Dropdown options are shown in a tiny font that's very hard to read, a poor user experience. The fix is to use Chrome, Opera, Vivaldi, Safari, or anything except Firefox.

Answer (score 6):

FireFox has had issues with this for a long time (*see bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=910022*).

The current status as mentioned in [MDN `<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#Browser_compatibility)

> 3. When Mozilla introduced dedicated content threads to Firefox (through the Electrolysis, or e10s, project), support for styling `<option>` elements was removed temporarily. Starting in Firefox 54, you can apply foreground and background colors to `<option>` elements again, using the `color` and `background-color` CSS properties. See bug 910022 for more information. Note that this is still disabled in Linux due to lack of contrast (see bug 1338283 for progress on this)

---

So currently only `color` and `background-color` can be customized.

Comment: funny enough, before my update to FF57, it looked just fine.

Comment: This is still occurring in Firefox 65.0.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.1.  However, it does not occur if the select element has a size attribute greater than 1.